# How to read JSON values from POST Request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, json, node.js, swift

How can I read values from POST request sent from client? I send `POST` request from client in Swift like so:

```
    let data = [ "tokenId": "tokenId-12345",
                 "title": "Congrats! You have a new follower.",
                 "body" : " John Doe is now following you.",
                 "photoUrl" : "url" ]

    let body = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .sortedKeys)
    request.httpBody = body
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // handle response.
    }
```

On backend I need to get values from request, so I can send push notification.

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 var serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

 exports.isMutual = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    if (request.params) {

        // get values. This doesn't work..
        var title = request.params.title;
        var body = request.params.body;
        var icon = request.params.photoUrl;

        const payload = {
            notification: {
              title:title,
              body: body,
              icon: icon
            }
          };

        response.send(payload);
        console.log(payload);
    }

   });
```

Comment: `var title = request.body.title;` `var body = request.body.body;` `var icon = request.body.photoUrl;` more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request

Comment: @Peter Not working. log shows: `{ notification: { title: undefined, body: undefined, icon: undefined } }`. Any reason why this might be?

Comment: what the `console.log` for `request.body`?

Comment: log shows: `{ '{"body":" John Doe is now following you.","photoUrl":"url","title":"Congrats! You have a new follower.","tokenId":"tokenId-12345"}': '' }`

Comment: ohh i see the whole post message is a key of the object. try this: `var body = JSON.parse(Object.keys(request.body)[0]); console.log(body)` - this is an ugly and quick fix don't use it in production, Just try to figure out whats went wrong with the body parser)

Comment: @Peter Thanks, this worked. Parsing JSON and sending to Apple Push Notification Service is the only responsibility of this function. It doesn't get any more complex than this. Why else wouldn't I use this in production? Really new to javascript so I don't have time to dig deeper and figure out something more elegant.

Comment: because something wrong with the post, or with the body parser and this is a workaround the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use `query`

```
    var title = request.query.title;
    var body = request.query.body;
    var icon = request.query.photoUrl;
```

Also, remove  `if (request.params)`

Do

```
 if(title && body && icon){ 
     // do something
 }
```

Comment: No luck. log: `{ notification: { title: undefined, body: undefined, icon: undefined } }`. I already removed `if (request.params)` before testing.

Comment: can you try from the web broswer?

Comment: i did firebase functions a while back. https://github.com/huyvanvo94/university-library-mobile-app/blob/master/firebase-functions/functions/index.js

Comment: I ultimately got working solution from Peter. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: on client side was your data structured the same as mine? Just key/value pairs?

Comment: some like: "www.url.com/?test=1". I just built the url.

Comment: When ready to send a notification to device I call sendToDevice method which takes a String as an argument. A resource from GitHub says its a  device notification token. Firebase says its a "registration token that comes from the client FCM SDKs". What should be the input here?

Comment: Should put on another question. Stackoverflow does not like this.

Answer (score 0):

To use `request.query.myKey`, add `URLQueryItem`'s to the url from client, rather than adding dictionary to `urlRequest` `body`.

```
   var urlComponents: URLComponents {
            var components = URLComponents(string: urlString)!
            let tokenIdQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "TokenId", value: "tokenId-12345")
            let titleQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "title", value: "Congrats! You have a new follower.")
            let bodyQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "body", value: "John Doe is now following you")
            let photoUrlQueryItem  = URLQueryItem(name: "photoUrl", value: "photoUrl...")
            components.queryItems = [tokenIdQueryItem, titleQueryItem, bodyQueryItem, photoUrlQueryItem]
            return components
        }

   var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
```